Tailwind CSS and Next.js issues

I'm simply trying to see colors or anything but when I load the test page, CSS file is not loading. I've followed various fixes suggested here, but none have been successful. I'm using the latest version of Next.js, and I've even deleted the .next folder and rebuilt it, but it still isn’t functioning.
I'm testing this on a simple page because it's not working in my main app.
I've tried CSS using:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

and:
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

File paths:

\app\test.tsx

\app\globals.css


My layout.tsx code:
"use client"; // Enable Client Component behavior

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import "./globals.css"; // Ensure this path is correct

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Your App Title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Your App Description" />
      </head>
      <body className="bg-gray-100">{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

postcss.config.js:
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};

tailwind.config.js:
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./features/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

test.tsx test page:
// pages/test.tsx
const TestPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-100">
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold text-blue-500">Tailwind CSS is Working!</h1>
      <p className="mt-4 text-gray-700">This is a test page.</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestPage;


Make sure the files you are trying to use Tailwind classes in is included in the content array in tailwind.config.js. It's hard to tell exactly what's going on without a Minimal Reproducible Example, but you mentioned your files are within the app folder, so I'd try adding that to your config.

I got this to work finally. I was using nextauth for login pages and it asked me to create signin pages outside of my app folder which caused this issue. Once I moved everything to the app folder, this started working.
